# Where to get MSDN Help Viewer for 2010 like earlier MSDN with Index, Tree and one window?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msdn

I upgraded to Visual Studio 2010 RC, and I remember filling one big form for MSDN help improvement campaign and I was wondering I will get to see a Help Viewer like MSDN included in Visual Studio 2008, which included One Program (Not IE), Index and the way to view preferred language setting.

Google results shows that there were headlines that Microsoft Help Viewer released for 2010 RC, but where is it? is it the same one which opens in IE and has absolute difficult way to view it?

Current MSDN opening in IE is so inconvenient, there is no index, there is no grouping of content, like I typed search for TextBox and it showed up for ASP.NET, WinForms and I got lost to find out the reference in multiple pages for search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general opinion seems to be that the help viewer in Visual Studio 2010 is a giant step backwards. Just take a look at the comments from [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2010/01/27/playing-back-the-help-feedback.aspx).

We'll probably see a bunch of 3rd party viewers appearing. Currently there's [H3Viewer](http://mshcmigrate.helpmvp.com/viewer), which has tree navigation and index, but it's pretty slow.

Comment: Thanks I did get the H3Viewer, however there is no bug reporting enabled and its very slow and the latest version does not load index at all...